# How do I pass dynamic parameters from amp-ad to amp-analytics?

Tags: amp-html, amp-analytics

I am trying to make our ad-network integration to amp now.
So I am troubled with the `in-view` tracking method of `amp-ad`.
If anyone has a good solution, would you please help me?

Our ad-network works as follows:

1. The media side requests ad-request
2. The ad-network side returns `ad-info` and `token`
3. The media side uses `ad-info` to display ad
4. The media side uses `token` to tracking `in-view`

`amp-ad` is handled inside an iframe when displaying ad.
Therefore, I can not give a token to `in-view-tracking-url` to fire with `amp-analytics`.
Would you please solve this?

I'm sorry that my English is not good.
Thanks.

Comment: There is a reason why we thought about using `amp-analytics`.
`amp-ad` displays advertisements inside an iframe.
When we decide whether or not the user saw the ad, we also have to monitor the parents.
This method is a difficult if `iframe` are nested. (I do not need to think?)
Therefore, I thought that it would be easier to use `amp-analytics`.

Comment: Try to check this documentation of [amp-analytics](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-analytics) and this documentation on how to [add Analytics to your AMP pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/). These two documentation can tell you the only things that you can do with amp-analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it solved, I reported.

1. It is not possible to pass dynamic parameters from `amp-ad` to`amp-analytics`.
2. To measure `in-view` of`amp-ad`, use:
   https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/63e58efb2099a5ff819c3486bfa65a63d017273e/ads/README.md#ad-viewability

Yay !